# Conditional formatting of more than one blank cells

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-formatting

I have a list of names of people and 4 different trainings. 
I would like to format my list so that if a person:

- has not attended any of the trainings (i.e. 4 blanks) the colour of the entire row is red
- has attended 1 of 4 trainings the colour of the entire row is pink (in this case one cell will have a 'date' value and the remaining 3 cells will be blank)
- has attended 2 of 4 trainings the colour of the entire row is orange (in this case two cells will have a 'date' value and the other 2 cells will be blank)
- has attended 3 of 4 trainings the colour of the entire row is yellow (in this case three cells will have a 'date' value and the other 1 cell will be blank)
- has attended all (4 of 4) trainings the colour of the entire row is green (no blank cells, all cells contain a date value)

Answer (score 0):

Let your data be in `A2:E11` range.

Select this range. With selected range go to *"Conditional Formatting -> New Rule..."*

[image]

---

**1.**

> has attended 1 of 4 trainings the colour of the entire row is pink (in
>   this case one cell will have a 'date' value and the remaining 3 cells
>   will be blank)

create new rule with following formula: `=COUNTBLANK($B2:$E2)=3` and press *"OK"*

[image]

---

**2.**

> has attended 2 of 4 trainings the colour of the entire row is orange
>   (in this case two cells will have a 'date' value and the other 2 cells
>   will be blank)

With selected range go to *"Conditional Formatting -> New Rule..."*

create new rule with following formula: `=COUNTBLANK($B2:$E2)=2` and press *"OK"*

[image]

---

**3.**

> has attended 3 of 4 trainings the colour of the entire row is yellow
>   (in this case three cells will have a 'date' value and the other 1
>   cell will be blank)

With selected range go to *"Conditional Formatting -> New Rule..."*

create new rule with following formula: `=COUNTBLANK($B2:$E2)=1` and press *"OK"*

[image]

---

**4.**

> has attended all (4 of 4) trainings the colour of the entire row is
>   green (no blank cells, all cells contain a date value)

With selected range go to *"Conditional Formatting -> New Rule..."*

create new rule with following formula: `=COUNTBLANK($B2:$E2)=0` and press *"OK"*

[image]

---

**5.**

> has not attended any of the trainings (i.e. 4 blanks) the colour of
>   the entire row is red

**There are two options to to achieve this**

**a)** With selected range go to *"Conditional Formatting -> New Rule..."*

create new rule with following formula: `=COUNTBLANK($B2:$E2)=4` and press *"OK"*

[image]

**b)** With selected range go to *"Fill Color"* and choose *"Red color"*

[image]

---

**Result:**

[image]